# pytables - hdf appears empty when it is not

Tags: python, pytables

I have some h5 files I'm trying to read with `pytables`, i.e.:

```
>>> from pandas.io.pytables import HDFStore
>>> filestore = HDFStore('serpentine_xrf4t1_72016_swedge.h5', mode='r')
>>> filestore.keys()
[]
```

The file appears to be empty. However, if I open it with HDFView, the file is clearly not empty and has the data I want. Trying another way:

```
from pandas.io.pytables import read_hdf
read_hdf('serpentine_xrf4t1_72016_swedge.h5', 'pds_image')
```

I get

```
TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

What does that mean? The file definitely has the dataset `pds_image`, as I can load the file in HDFView as noted earlier and look at it. So I'm very confused. How can I figure out what's going on here? I'm using python3.4, pandas 0.13.1, tables 3.1.1.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with pandas - not pytables.  I would bring it up with them.